# Set a variable according to another variable

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

I am working on a gitlab-ci project.
I have a variable `A` that I retrieve from a form.
I have to set another variable `B` in my playbook.

If `A` matches a certain regex, `B` should be `' -p A'` else `B` should be an empty string `''`.
This should be written in an Ansible file.

I have tried

```yaml
- set_fact: 
  B="{{ ' -p ' + A}}"
  when: A is regex("^\\d{1,8}$")
```

but it didn't work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What I am kind of guessing is that the regex you wrote does not do what you think it does. What is the content of `A` and could you explain in **words** what is should match?

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have three issues, I would say:

1. you should use an [inline *if* expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression) of Jinja rather than a `when`
2. the backslash of the digit pattern have to be escaped to produce a valid in YAML: `\\d`
3. I guess the regex do not match what you think it does, to match between one and eight digit(s), the quantifier have to be used with a **comma** (`,`) to separate the minimum and the maximum repetition of the previous pattern, not a dash (`-`): `\\d{1,8}`

All together

```yaml
 - set_fact: 
     B: "{{ ' -p ' ~ migration_time if A is regex('^\\d{1,8}$') else '' }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        B: "{{ ' -p ' ~ migration_time if A is regex('^\\d{1,8}$') else '' }}"
      vars:
        A: 20220127
        migration_time: 2022-01-27
    
    - debug:
        var: B
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  B: ' -p 2022-01-27'
```

---

Now, if my assumptions on your regex not matching what you meant are incorrect, here is a valid playbook matching that exact scenario.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        B: "{{ ' -p ' ~ migration_time if A is regex('^\\d{1-8}$') else '' }}"
      vars:
        ## This is the value that will make `A` match,
        ## but, I do suspect this is not what you meant
        ## and I guess you meant `^\\d{1,8}$`, rather in your regex.
        A: '1{1-8}' 
        migration_time: 2022-01-27
    
    - debug:
        var: B
```

This yields:

```
TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  B: ' -p 2022-01-27'
```

Comment: There's actually a 4th issues: the yaml indentation for the `set_fact` task is incorrect in the question and will fire a syntax error. The ini style assignment is probably not a good practice either but does the job (with the correct indentation).

Comment: @Zeitounator TBH, I was searching recently any educated (possibly core maintainer) point of view on this alternative syntax. I think I kind of saw one saying it shouldn't be used anymore but cannot land on that specific comment anymore.

Comment: all I can say is that [the discussion did not lead to any clear consensus back in 2014 already](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/GfJBkzuTTNM/m/RsoLu4P4JHgJ) I don't think the syntax will be dropped any time especially because you have no other choice for issuing ad_hoc commands. My remark above about good practice was motivated by the fact the parameter is on a new line and on its own. It does not really make sense IMO in that situation to use a key=val syntax. But I'll stop here to not reproduce the above linked discussion 8 years later ;)

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the link. The ground might have changed since 2014, as the very opening of this thread stand on the ground that Jeff is referring to the fact that the documentation is using the `k=v` syntax, when, in nowadays documentation, I don't see it used anywhere anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**If A matches a certain regex, B should be ' -p A' else B should be an empty string ''.**"*

A: Use the filter *ternary*, e.g.

```yaml
  B: "{{ (A is regex('^\\d{1,8}$'))|ternary(' -p ' ~ A, '') }}"
```

Test it

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: 'A: {{ A }} -> B: "{{ B }}"'
      loop:
        - 1234567
        - 12345678
        - 123456789
        - xyz12345
      loop_control:
        loop_var: A
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'A: 1234567 -> B: " -p 1234567"'
  msg: 'A: 12345678 -> B: " -p 12345678"'
  msg: 'A: 123456789 -> B: ""'
  msg: 'A: xyz12345 -> B: ""'
```

---

Q: *"**This should be written in an Ansible file.**"*

A: You can put it into a file if you want to, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat set_B.yml 
B: "{{ (A is regex('^\\d{1,8}$'))|ternary(' -p ' ~ A, '') }}"
```

Then you can use it in many ways, e.g. use *include_vars*

```yaml
    - include_vars: set_B.yml
```

or put it into the *group_vars*, *host_vars*, ... See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)